# Why doesn't Alias register on IGNIS blockchain when using the setAlias API?

Tags: ardor, ignis

I am trying to create an Alias on the Ignis child chain of Ardor. Everything seems to work properly the using the setAlias API in the Ardor API Console. I see the transaction for a brief time in my dashboard and it disappears without registering my Alias.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Bitcoin.

Comment: From the rules of this site: "Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, ZCash, Dogecoin, and NXT."